# How to exclude pages from nav menu

Tags: wordpress

How can I exclude page(s) from nav menu? I found some examples where field called "**exclude**" was added to args and reportedly it worked. Maybe it's just deprecated. I have version 4.1.5.

My current code is:

```
$avia_theme_location = 'avia';
$avia_menu_class = $avia_theme_location . '-menu';
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => $avia_theme_location,
    'menu_id' => $avia_menu_class,
    'exclude' => '29, 30, 31, 32',
    'menu_class' => 'menu av-main-nav',
    'container_class' => $avia_menu_class.' av-main-nav-wrap'.$icon_beside,
    'fallback_cb' => 'avia_fallback_menu',
    'walker' => new avia_responsive_mega_menu()
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Where 29,30,31 and 32 are pages IDs what I want to exclude and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
$args = array(
    // Other values,
    'exclude' => array(29,30,31,32) // <-- Addedd ids to exclude
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
Instead of

```
'exclude' => '29, 30, 31, 32',
```

Try,

```
'post__not_in' => array( 29, 30, 31, 32 ),
```

This is in [wordpress official site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: But don't work in my case. Finally I found my own solution. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved myself. This was important:
'fallback_cb' => 'avia_fallback_menu'

I wanted to exclude Woocommerce pages in Enfold theme. So I found that callback function in file class-megamenu.php and I now it looks like this:

```
function avia_fallback_menu()
{
    $current = "";
    $exclude= (avia_get_option('frontpage').",".get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' ).",".get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_page_id' ).",".get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ).",".get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ));
    if (is_front_page()){$current = "class='current-menu-item'";}
    if ($exclude) $exclude ="&exclude=".$exclude;
    echo "<div class='fallback_menu av-main-nav-wrap'>";
    echo "<ul class='avia_mega menu av-main-nav'>";
    echo "<li $current><a href='".get_bloginfo('url')."'>".__('Domov','avia_framework')."</a></li>";
    wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order'.$exclude);
    echo apply_filters('avf_fallback_menu_items', "", 'fallback_menu');
    echo "</ul></div>";
}
```